# How to use Oracle GREATEST() Function like this?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

For example I have this

```
select a.f1, b.f1, greatest(a.f2 - sum(b.f2)) as qty ...
```

And so, what can I do with sum(b.f2)? How I can get `sum()` of rows from table `b`, by field `b.f2` and evaluate it in expression `greatest(a.f2 - sum(b.f2))`?

```
    select t1.gid,
    greatest((t1.qty - sum(t2.qty) - t1.otherqty - t1.anotherqty), 0) as QTY,
  from bigtable t1
    inner join ambigioustable t2 on t2.gid = t1.gid
  group by 
    t1.gid,
    t1.qty,
    t1.otherqty, 
    t1.anotherqty,
      order by t1.gid;
```

I expect that this query does calculation over entries like this

```
---|gid|---|qty|--|label|---
     1       20    some item
     1       2     some item
     1       3     some item
     2       4     som another item
     ...
```

etc.

Am I right about this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have shown - do you get an error? Wrong results? What are you trying to show in that expression - are you confusing `greatest()` with `max()`, perhaps? It would be helpful to show the whole query, sample data and both current and expected results.

Comment: I think you might have [`greatest`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/GREATEST.html) mixed up with [`max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/MAX.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GREATEST` function in Oracle is primarily a scalar function, meaning that it takes as input scalar values, usually from a single row, and returns the largest value.  If I read your question correctly, you want to find the row or rows corresponding to the largest difference between `f2` field values.  This requires doing a calculation across the entire table/result set.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT a_f1, b_f1, diff
FROM
(
    SELECT a.f1 AS a_f1, b.f1 AS b_f1, a.f2 - b.f1 AS diff,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.f2 - b.f2 DESC) AS rn
    FROM tableA a
    INNER JOIN tableB b
        ON a.id = b.id
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Note: If you don't care about the direction of the difference, then you can use `ORDER BY (ABS(a.f2 - b.f2))` in the call to `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Actually i need something like `inner join (select sum(...) as qty, id  from table left outer join) as t1` and then use `t1` in `greatest(t2.qty - t1.qty)`

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output to your question.

Comment: Sorry for waiting, this answer helps alot! Thank you.